# Should a typedef be both in the class definition and class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, scope, typedef

I'm learning C++. I know that C++ is a bit more verbose than most other languages, however defining a `typedef` in a struct/ class declaration and then again in the struct/ class definition got me thinking if there isn't a better or more central place for the `typedef` where it only has to be defined once, and whether this follows what is thought of as C++ best practices. I couldn't find anything in particular about this on the web.

Moving the `typedef` to a more global place seems inappropriate and the `typedef` is both used for the definition and implementation of the method within the struct.

```
//--ProductFilter.h--
struct ProductFilter {
    typedef std::vector<Product*> Items;
    static Items by_color(Items items, Color color);
};

//--ProductFilter.cpp--
typedef std::vector<Product*> Items;
Items ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) {
    Items result;
    for (auto& item : items)
        if (item->color == color)
            result.push_back(item);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to defined the typedef in the class declaration and class definition.  The reason you are doing so is that when you do

```
Items ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) {
    Items result;
    for (auto& item : items)
        if (item->color == color)
            result.push_back(item);
    return result;
}
```

The `Items` for the return type is not scoped to the class, so `Items` needs to be a name in the global scope.  If you use

```
ProductFilter::Items ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) {
    Items result;
    for (auto& item : items)
        if (item->color == color)
            result.push_back(item);
    return result;
}
```

Then you no longer have this issue and you can just have the typedef in the class declaration.

---

The reason you don't need to do `ProductFilter::Items` in

```
ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color)
```

is because the `ProductFilter::` puts you in the scope of the class so you can use names defined in the class without having to qualify them.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition should be:

```
ProductFilter::Items ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color)
{
    // ...
}
```

or, with trailing return type:

```
auto ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) -> Items 
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two typdefs actually declare two different aliases for the same type. One is `ProductFilter::Items` the other is `Items` in the global namespace.

Actually I am not sure of the rules which one you get when writing `Items` within the scope of `ProductFilter`, though it doesnt really matter as they are identical anyhow.

You only need either of them. Which one you pick depends on in which scope you want declare it. If `Items` semantically belongs to `ProductFilter` then I'd choose the first and put it in the declaration only.

You would have to qualify the return type as `ProductFilter::Items` (or use trailing return type).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the qualified name of the typedef outside the class scope

```
ProductFilter::Items ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) {
    Items result;
    for (auto& item : items)
        if (item->color == color)
            result.push_back(item);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Or `auto ProductFilter::by_color(Items items, Color color) -> Items`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with wanting to get the type out of that class in the cpp for practical reasons. You just should not redefine, but alias it instead :

```cpp
// top of cpp file
using Items = ProductFilter::Items;
```

If the type of Items ever changes, the alias will not need to be rewritten.